# c char access violation error

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

I want a method, that fix umlauts (äöü) for a german console application

```
#define oe (unsigned char)148
[...]

char* fixUmlauts(char string[]) {
  for(int i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++) {
    switch(string[i]) {
      [...]

      case 'ö':
        string[i] = oe;
        break;

      [...]
    }
  }

  return string;
}
```

But I get an error while I run this:

```
printf(fixUmlauts("Hallöle\n"));
```

> Access Violation when writing at position 0x01276BE4.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't modify a string literal `Hallöle\n`. You should copy it into a `char` array and then modify that:

```
char string[] = "Hallöle\n";
fixUmlauts(string);
```

Comment: Thats why i does not like c

Comment: @Denni007 then don't code in [tag:c]. There are plenty of languages you can use, it depends on your skills and how much you understand the representation of things. But certainly each task requires the most suitable language, you can't use the same language for everything except that you can use [tag:c] for everything (*although you shouldn't*). It's not hard.

Comment: Year I love programming, but I need C for the university. And every time I stuck on those things